Replace () with range with variable values
I am facing difficulty in replacing values from a range variables.
My objective is to find and replace Column G with range variables I have in Column A.
The find values "0260203700" are fixed.
While the replacement values I need them to be the variables in range Column A.
Column G is a URL need to find "0260203700" and replace with variables found in range Column A.
Can anyone help to advise or guide me?
Thank you.
Sub Bulk_Replace()

Dim listRng As Range

Dim rep As Range

Dim findThis As String

Dim replaceWith As String



With Worksheets("Sheet1")

       Set listRng = .Range(Cells(2, "A"), Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp))

 End With

For Each rep In listRng

If Len(rep.Value) = 0 Then GoTo skip   ''' Skip empty cells

    findThis = rep.Value

    replaceWith = rep.Offset(0, 1).Value

    On Error GoTo skip    ''' If not found

    Range("G2:G").Replace What:=findThis, Replacement:=replaceWith

skip: '' Next in line

Next rep

               

End Sub



Load Col A and G into array
Replace the data in memory
Write output to Col G all at once

Option Explicit
Sub Bulk_Replace()
    Dim listRng As Range
    Dim aColG, aColA, i As Long, sVal As String
    Const SKEY = "0260203700"
    With Worksheets("Sheet1")
        Dim lastRow As Long: lastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "G").End(xlUp).Row
        Set listRng = .Range("G1:G" & lastRow)
        aColG = listRng.Value
        aColA = .Range("A1:A" & lastRow).Value
    End With
    For i = LBound(aColG) To UBound(aColG)
        sVal = aColG(i, 1)
        If InStr(sVal, SKEY) > 0 Then
            aColG(i, 1) = Replace(sVal, SKEY, aColA(i, 1))
        End If
    Next
    listRng.Value = aColG
End Sub

